# Return mock list on given JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I'm having a problem wanting to mock the return of a list with JUnit. I tried this:

```
given(loan.getExternalReferences().stream()
   .filter(er -> er.getType() == ReferenceType.ORIGINATION_PLATFORM_FUND)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())).willReturn(anyList());
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is it exactly that you try to accomplish here? Do wnat to return an emptylist once the entire pipeline has ran its course?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code?